# YouTube "Unlist live replay once stream ends" liveBroadcasts api

Tags: api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Looking over the documentation on the [insert for livebroadcasts api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) and I don't see a way to set this value to true. Is there a way to set this during insert?

[image: screenshot of setting]